# Adding ajax result to jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I have a dialog where user selects yes or no in a radio button form.  Based on selection, i need to load different forms into the same dialog. I cant figure out how to accomplish this.

```
$('#newClientDialog').dialog({
  width:1000,
  height:1000,
  modal:true
});
```

form ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  data:{'sfid' : sfid,
        '_token' : token},
  url:"someUrl",
  success:function(result){
    $('#XXXX').html(result);
  }
```

the main page with the dialog divs:

```
<div id='newClientDialog'></div>
```

I have tried

```
<div id='newClientDialog'><div id='formResult'></div></div>
```

and the success of ajax:

```
$('#formResult').html(result);
```

but the formResult div doesnt exist in the dialog div

Comment: Try `console.log(result)` in the success callback... To make sure there is a `result`.

Comment: there is a response, i just dont know where to put it., i cant get formresult div to exist

Comment: Do you have this `<div id='newClientDialog'><div id='formResult'></div></div>` in the HTML marckup or not?

Comment: yea, but when i look at debug in chrome, its not there.

Comment: Maybe you have some code that removes it? I can't guess.